# Ramda Converting to Free-Point Style

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I haven't really found a good resource for this sort of thing. Apologies in advance if this question has been asked, though I couldn't quite find the answer (perhaps due to a lack of knowing how to search.

I have this function. It's like `R.prepend`/`R.append`, but it shoves a value into the middle of a list instead.

```js
const insertMiddle = (val, arr) => 
  R.insert(Math.floor(arr.length/2), val, arr);
```

I'm just learning functional programming, so I'm writing a program with as much free-point-style as possible. Even if that takes away from readability a bit, I just like to see it done. Bend my brain to start thinking functionally and seeing how to solve problems that way.

Here's what I've done:

```js
const halfLength = R.compose(
  Math.floor,
  R.divide(R.__, 2),
  R.prop('length')
);

// ----
const insertMiddle = (val, arr) =>
  R.insert(halfLength(arr), val, arr);
// ---- OR
const insertMiddle = (val, arr) =>
  R.insert(halfLength(arr), val, R.identity(arr));
```

This of course isn't free-point yet.

Here is ostensibly the next step:

```js
const insertMiddle = (val, arr) => 
  R.insert(R.__, val)(halfLength(arr), R.identity(arr));
```

Now if I can get `(halfLength(arr), R.identity(arr))` to be point-free, I'll be left with a function that just needs `val`.

---

Am I going about this the right way? What happens next?

How does:

- `x => foo(bar(x), x)` or
- `x => foo(bar(x),baz(x))`

become point free?

Comment: Point-free doesn't make it more functional, just more complicated IMHO.

Comment: @customcommander I'm pretty new to this, but my experience so far has been that it's a mixed bag. Sometimes it simplifies things dramatically and others it really doesn't. Even so, I'd like to learn how to make that distinction for myself by playing around with both ends of that spectrum

Comment: Absolutely. Just know when it's time to stop. (I went there myself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramda does offer tools to make it easier to write points-free code.  And if you are just fiddling around, trying to see how they work, we can do all sorts of things with them.  But I would reiterate that the goal should be understandable code.  Use points-free when it helps with readability; skip it when it doesn't.

There are a few Ramda functions specifically designed for this.  (Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.)  [`useWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith), [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge), and [`nthArg`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#nthArg) are prominent among these.

We can use `converge` and `nthArg` to get this to work:

```js
const {compose, divide, __, prop, converge, insert, pipe, nthArg} = R

const halfLength = compose (
  Math .floor,
  divide (__, 2),
  prop ('length')
)

const insertMiddle = converge (insert, [pipe (nthArg (1), halfLength), nthArg (0), nthArg (1)])

console .log (insertMiddle (42, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

We could even go whole-hog and inline `halfLength`

```js
const insertMiddle = converge (insert, [
  pipe (nthArg (1), prop ('length'), divide (__, 2), Math .floor), 
  nthArg (0), 
  nthArg (1)
])
```

Again, as a learning exercise, this is fine.  But I find either of those a lot less readable than a simple function, using only a bit of Ramda:

```js
const insertMiddle = (x, xs) =>
  insert ((xs .length >> 1), x, xs)
```

or a plain vanilla version:

```js
const insertMiddle = (x, xs, mid = xs .length >> 1) =>
  [... xs .slice (0, mid), x, ... xs .slice (mid)]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer! This is exactly the kind of help I was after. I find I learn much faster if I take an idea/concept to an absurd extreme and then scale it back rather than attempting to use it within reason right out of the gate.

Answer (score 1):

The R.chain called with two functions - chain(f, g)(x) is the equivalent of f(g(x), x). If with change the order of the last two parameters of R.insert (value & array), we can use it to create `insertMiddle`:

```js
const { compose, divide, __, prop, curry, chain, insert } = R

const halfLength = compose(
  Math.floor,
  divide(__, 2),
  prop('length')
)

const flippedInsert = curry((idx, val, arr) => insert(idx, arr, val))

const insertMiddle = chain(flippedInsert, halfLength)

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const result = insertMiddle(arr)('*')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I keep wondering if Ramda should create something like lodash's `rearg`.  It would help with `flippedInsert`.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking while trying to find a nice way to do so :)